# Task Parallel.ForEach loop Error when removing items "Index was outside the bounds of the array. "

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to remove items for a generic list of objects in a foreach loop. When I am doing same thing with task parallel library loop i am getting error.
**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

following is my code

```
List<string> lstSubscriberDidTransaction = ...; // Initialization
var lstSubscriber = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubscriberInfoShortenObject>>(somestring);

foreach (string strId in lstSubscriberDidTransaction)
{
    lstSubscriber.RemoveAll(h => h != null && h.Msisdn == strId);
}

//Parallel.ForEach(lstSubscriberDidTransaction, msisdn => lstSubscriber.RemoveAll(h => h != null && h.Msisdn == msisdn));
```

Can somebody help me in it
I am using .net 3.5. for task parallel library with http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary

Comment: Question Viewed more then 1000 times but some one have negative marked it. I hope there should be a necessary comment when someone downvote so that question asker can get idea what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List` class is not designed for concurrent write (/remove) operations, as stated in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but
>   issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read.
>   To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write
>   operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads
>   for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>   For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the
>   System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe
>   alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

For data structures supporting concurrent access, see [this linked article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To clarify why your problem arises from the `List` class:
The `RemoveAll` operation will iterate over the list instance and match the predicate against every contained instance. If the predicate evaluates to true, the index of the matched instance will be used to remove the entry. If the operation is performed in a concurrent matter, another thread may have already removed another entry, so the index is no longer valid or will point to another instance not matching the predicate. The operation is therefore not threadsafe and will not give the results you are expecting.
Just for your viewing pleasure, the given code is the decompiled method from the `List` class:

```
public int RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)
{
  if (match == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
  int index1 = 0;
  while (index1 < this._size && !match(this._items[index1]))
    ++index1;
  if (index1 >= this._size)
    return 0;
  int index2 = index1 + 1;
  while (index2 < this._size)
  {
    while (index2 < this._size && match(this._items[index2]))
      ++index2;
    if (index2 < this._size)
      this._items[index1++] = this._items[index2++];
  }
  Array.Clear((Array) this._items, index1, this._size - index1);
  int num = this._size - index1;
  this._size = index1;
  ++this._version;
  return num;
}
```

---

To give you some more hints:
Do not use parallel code, as it will not help you without big changes. Optimize your look up data structure and simplify your statement.

```
HashSet<string> lstSubscriberDidTransaction = ...
...

lstSubscriber.RemoveAll(h => h != null && lstSubscriberDidTransaction.Contains(h.Msisdn))
```

This should improve the performance, for any more help we would need more insight into your code.

Comment: You can try `Parallel.ForEach(lstSubscriberDidTransaction.ToArray() `

Comment: it seems like he's iterating 2 different sources. `lstSubscriberDidTransaction` and `lstSubscriber`

Comment: `RemoveAll` iterates the list as well, so on `lstSubscriber` he is reading and writing in a concurrent manner.

Comment: lstSubscriberDidTransaction is a simple List<string> as i shown in code string strId in lstSubscriberDidTransaction while lstSubscriber  is List<SubscriberInfoShortenObject>

Comment: @KamranShahid `lstSubscriberDidTransaction` is not defined in the given code snippet

Comment: Matten can you help which thread safe concurrent list i can replace in my code var lstSubscriber = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubscriberInfoShortenObject>>(somestring);

Comment: @KamranShahid Do not use parallel code as it is not helpful in your case. Simply call `lstSubscriber.RemoveAll(h => h != null && lstSubscriberDidTransaction.Contains(h.Msisdn));`

Comment: Thanks Matten. One thing i found out is that the thread safe collection for task parallel libarary is introduced in 4.0 while i am using .net 3.5.
I am almost using the code as you mentioned but for collection of 10,000 + records it takes time which i wants to distribute on cores to finish it earlier

Comment: @KamranShahid optimize the data structures, see my updated answers.

Comment: Thanks Matten. Just implemented it